# Buscar las coincidencias de un string en un array y colocarlo en negrita

Tags: javascript, real-time

A ver, explico: se crea un array con cada una de las palabras escritas en el input, ejemplo:

`const arr = ['se', 'crea', 'un', 'array', 'con', 'cada', 'una', 'de', 'las', 'palabras', 'escritas', 'en', 'el', 'input']`

Ahora, de este array quiero buscar en este string:

`Las palabras de los input son muy importantes para los array`

Las palabras que coincidan con cada elemento del array y colocarlo en negrita quedando así:
**Las palabras de** los **input** son muy importantes para los **array**

Tomando en cuenta que las palabras que aparecen y están en el array son `['las', 'palabras', 'de', 'input', 'array']`

Lo he intentado con el siguiente código pero solo se coloca en negrita el último elemento:

```
     input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
         let boxSearch = input.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.search-match')
         boxSearch.innerHTML = ''
         let text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
         for (let item of dataAutocomplete) {
                let name = item.name.toLowerCase();
                let nameFilter = name.replace(text, `<strong>${ text }</strong>`)
                var filterLettering = text.split(' ');
                var yes = 0;
                let filterText;
                for (var filter of filterLettering) {
                    if (name.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                        yes++;
                        filterText = name.replaceAll(filter, `<strong>${ filter }</strong>`)
                    }
                }

                if (yes === filterLettering.length) {
                    boxSearch.innerHTML += /*html*/ ` 
                    <div class="item-match">
                        <span style="text-transform: capitalize;"> 
                        ${ filterText }
                        </span>
                    </div>` 
                }
          }
     })
```

¿Alguno me podría ayudar por favor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Más sencillo, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Capturas al valor de tu input y a la etiqueta `span`:

  ```
  const texto = document.getElementById('texto').value;
  const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  ```
- En tu `span` hacemos un `innerHTML` lo siguiente:

  - Al `texto` (el valor del input) hacemos un `split()`, usando al espacio   como separador, devolviendo un array, y cada palabra del input como los elementos del array.

    ```
    resultado.innerHTML = texto.split(' ')
    ```
  - Luego mapeamos a los elementos del array y en cada elemento verificamos si cumple la instrucción `arr.includes(palabra.toLowerCase())`, es decir, si la palabra se encuentra en el array `arr`. Si cumple, retornamos la palabra en negrita (con las etiquetas `<strong>`), si no cumple, retornamos la misma palabra.

    ```
    resultado.innerHTML = texto.split(' ').map(palabra => arr.includes(palabra.toLowerCase()) ? `<strong>${palabra}</strong>` : palabra)
    ```
  - Por último, juntamos todos los elementos del array en cadena con `join(' ')`.

    ```
     resultado.innerHTML = texto.split(' ').map(palabra => arr.includes(palabra.toLowerCase()) ? `<strong>${palabra}</strong>` : palabra).join(' ');
    ```

---

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const arr = ['se', 'crea', 'un', 'array', 'con', 'cada', 'una', 'de', 'las', 'palabras', 'escritas', 'en', 'el', 'input'];

function textoEnNegrita() {
  const texto = document.getElementById('texto').value;
  const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
  resultado.innerHTML = texto
    .split(' ')
    .map(palabra => arr.includes(palabra.toLowerCase()) ? `<strong>${palabra}</strong>` : palabra)
    .join(' ');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" oninput="textoEnNegrita()" />
<br><br>
<span id="resultado"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes recorrer la lista de palabras clave y reemplazar cada palabra por lo que quieras:

```js
const palabrasClave = ["esto", "es", "primera", "prueba"];

function ponerNegrillas(texto) {
  return texto.split(" ").map(word => palabrasClave.includes(word) ? `<strong>${word}</strong>` : word).join(" ");
}

document.write(ponerNegrillas("Esta es la primera prueba que hago de esto"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente usar [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll), para esto juntamos el array separando cada palabra con `|` para crear la expresión regular

```js
const arr = ['se', 'crea', 'un', 'array', 'con', 'cada', 'una', 'de', 'las', 'palabras', 'escritas', 'en', 'el', 'input'];

const patron = new RegExp(arr.map(a=> `\\b${a}\\b`).join('|'),"gi" ); //juntamos el array en un string, separando las palabras con |

const getOracionNegritas = oracion =>
 oracion.replaceAll(patron, a => `<strong>${a}</strong>`);

const o = "creación Las palabras de los input son muy importantes para los array creación crea";
document.write(getOracionNegritas(o) );
```

Comment: Hola Yuseff, la solución está incompleta, si una palabra de la oración es por ejemplo "creacion", le aplicaría el strong a parte de la palabra "crea", cuando no debería aplicale nada.

Comment: @Pipe muchas gracias por comentario, lo he corregido

Answer (score 1):

El error es que estás reemplazando la variable `filterText` en cada iteración del bucle, por lo que solo se guarda el resultado del último elemento coincidente. Para solucionarlo, puedes utilizar un array para almacenar todas las palabras coincidentes y luego unir ese array en un solo string para asignarlo a `filterText`.

***La forma correcta de hacerlo:***

Creamos un array `filterWords` para almacenar las palabras coincidentes. Si una palabra coincide, la envolvemos en etiquetas `<strong>` y la agregamos al array. Si no coincide, simplemente agregamos la palabra sin modificar al array.

Luego, unimos todas las palabras del array en un solo string utilizando el método `join(' ')`, para formar `filterText`, que contendrá las palabras coincidentes con las etiquetas `<strong>` correspondientes.

Finalmente, asignamos `filterText` al contenido HTML del elemento `boxSearch.innerHTML`, dentro del bucle for que recorre los elementos de `dataAutocomplete`.

```
input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    let boxSearch = input.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.search-match');
    boxSearch.innerHTML = '';

    let text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    let filterWords = [];

    for (let item of dataAutocomplete) {
        let name = item.name.toLowerCase();

        if (name.includes(text)) {
            let words = name.split(' ');

            for (let word of words) {
                if (text.includes(word)) {
                    filterWords.push(`<strong>${word}</strong>`);
                } else {
                    filterWords.push(word);
                }
            }

            let filterText = filterWords.join(' ');

            boxSearch.innerHTML += /*html*/ `
                <div class="item-match">
                    <span style="text-transform: capitalize;"> 
                        ${filterText}
                    </span>
                </div>`;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

podemos separar este problema en 2 partes:

1.- Identificar palabras en un array

2.- Poner palabras en negritas en HTMl.

vamos con un caso a la vez.

Para el primer caso, podemos utilizar `filter` en el array para filtrar elementos, de la siguiente forma:

```
const arr = ['se', 'crea', 'un', 'array', 'con', 'cada', 'una', 'de', 'las', 'palabras', 'escritas', 'en', 'el', 'input'];
const textToSearch = 'Las palabras de los input son muy importantes para los array';
const filterWords = arr.filter((element) => textToSearch.includes(element) === true);
console.log(filterWords); //["array", "de", "palabras", "input"]
```

Filter, lo que hace, es filtrar en un array según un criterio de búsqueda. En esta caso, utilizamos `includes()` para pedirle al filtro que, incluya sólo los elementos del array que estén dentro del texto a buscar. Como `includes()` devuelve un booleano, nos aseguramos que el resultado del método sea `true`.

Ahora, para las negritas, podemos recorrer el array generado para hacer el html deseado:

```
filterWords.forEach((word)=> {
  document.getElementById('body').innerHTML+= '<b>'+ word +'</b><br>'
});
```

`<b>` es un tag html que proporciona negritas.

`<br>` es un tag que se encarga de hacer un salto de línea.

Espero que mi respuesta pueda ayudarte.
¡Saludos!